# Is there a simple way to remove unused dependencies of Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a large Maven project with several modules and same have lots of Spring dependencies. working on same I found that we have lots of dependencies define in our process class but we are not using it any where,

Is there any appropriate plugin for tools which can search for all unused bean dependency of Spring.I google it and found that intelli j plug can help.

kindly let me know if you have any other tool or process to solve above issue.

Answer (score 2):

The Maven Dependency Plugin will help, especially the **dependency:analyze goal.**

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html

**dependency:analyze** analyzes the dependencies of this project and determines which are: used and declared; used and undeclared; unused and declared.

Comment: I don't think it's related to Spring dependency and my question.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I had the exact same question as this guy and your answer was exactly what I needed. It analyses the code-to-dependency links and shows the result at build. I am using Netbeans with a Maven project.